# Update table from another table and different database

Tags: mysql, sql

Basically, what I want to do is the following :
I have a table 'users' in my first database (prc), like this :

```
prc.user :
id_user : 45 | name_user : Test | login_user : test | pwd_user : test
[...]
```

And in my second database (named : prc_test)

```
prc_test.user
id_user : 45 | name_user : Test | login_user : test | pwd_user : test
[...]
```

The thing I want to do, is update all the "pwd_user" fields in "prc_test.user" with the values from pwd_user from "prc.user"
But in the prc_test.user, the id are not the same as in prc.user, so I thought of doing it with the "name_user", (there are no doubles).

Any clue in how I can do it ?
I searched on Google, but what I found is always for some specific cases, or for insert statements...

(I'm using MySQL5.5)

Thanks !

Comment: If the `id_user` columns don't match (your example shows them matching, btw), how can you tell that two records correspond to the same user?  I'd imagine that the `login_user` column is the most reliable, but it depends on your application.

Comment: He answered that in the very next sentence.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

```
UPDATE 
  prc.user, 
  prc_test.user 
SET 
  prc_test.user.pwd_user = prc.user.pwd_user
WHERE 
  prc_test.user.name_user = prc.user.name_user
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
prc_test.user
SET
prc_test.user.pwd_user = (SELECT prc.user.pwd_user FROM prc.user WHERE prc_test.user.id_user= prc.user.id_user)

Comment: The question already has an accepted valid answer. Why post another 'duplicate'?