# Migration script to map the user ids from one Db to Another where same mail exists

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create Migration script to map the user ids from one Db to Another where same mail exists.

So i have two different database with different usernames and password

Is it possible to do something like

```
update DB2.tbl_users
set Db2.tbl_users.IDinDb1=(
select DB1.tbl_users.ID from Db1.tbl_users 
where DB1.tbl_users.EMAIL=DB2.tbl_users.EMAIL
)
```

for all entries in Db2? Does mysql can do this trick or i must write php script to do that?

Running this code i got an error

```
#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108690/update-table-from-another-table-and-different-database). This should work:

```
update DB1.tbl_users, DB2.tbl_users
set DB2.tbl_users.IDinDb1 = DB1.tbl_users.ID
where DB1.tbl_users.email = DB2.tbl_users.email;
```